# How to colorize rows in tree view based on values of related models (Odoo)

Tags: xml, view, treeview, odoo, field

In the invoice tree view I want to colorize the rows based on the payment terms which were set in the invoice. Problem is, when I write the condition like this:

```
green:payment_term == 'Standard';
```

nothing happens. I guess, it's cause this refers to the related model "account.payment.terms" but not to the really needed name value of it's field "display_name".

So how could I access the value of the "display_name" field that I can write the right condition?

P.S. When I try to refer to it like this:

```
green:payment_term.display_name == 'Standard';
```

it says: "There is no attribute "display_name".

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You need to define a related (or computed) field on the invoice model for this requirement:

New API

```py
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    term_display_name = fields.Char(
        string="Payment Term Display Name", related="payment_term.display_name")
```

Old API

```py
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    _columns = {
        term_display_name = fields.related(
            "payment_term", "display_name", type="char",
        string="Payment Term Display Name")
    }
```

Then you can use `term_display_name` in your view.

Comment: I can confirm that this is true.